# I need to prevent duplicates in an access append query

Tags: sql-server, database

I have written append queries that take records from two subforms and insert them into an invoice items table. With either query the results are the same and just what I want except that if it is run again after a new record is added it will create duplicates of the already added records.
I have tried to use SELECT DISTINCT in the where clause for the ID field for the subform (Hours.ID), but it does nothing to change the results. See below.

Invoice items table = LineItemID | ProjectID | Project Name | HoursID | Investigator | Date Worked | Billable Hours | WorkCode | WorkCodeText | Charge | Total Charges

The query grabs fields from two tables to insert into the line items table with these arguments:

```
INSERT INTO tblInvoiceLineItems (
    ProjectID
    ,ProjectName
    ,Investigator
    ,DateWorked
    ,BillableHours
    ,Charge
    ,TotalCharges
    ,WorkCode
    ,[WorkCodeText]
    ,HoursID
    )
SELECT [Project Hours].Project
    ,[Project Hours].ProjectName
    ,[Project Hours].Investigator
    ,[Project Hours].[Date Worked]
    ,[Project Hours].[Billable Hours]
    ,tblWorkCodes.Charge
    ,[Project Hours] ! [Billable Hours] * [tblWorkCodes] ! [Charge] AS [Total Service Charges]
    ,[Project Hours].[Work Code]
    ,tblWorkCodes.WorkCode
    ,[Project Hours].ID
FROM tblWorkCodes
INNER JOIN [Project Hours] ON tblWorkCodes.WorkCodeID = [Project Hours].[Work Code]
WHERE (
        (([Project Hours].Project) = [Enter ID])
        AND (
            ([Project Hours].ID) IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT [Project Hours].ID
                FROM [Project Hours]
                )
            )
        );
```

Everything is fine except the last part where I try to add a distinct selection of the Hour table ID field, which runs but does not product the intended result. If a record is added to the hours table through the subform and the append query is run I get all the records not just the new record. I wish to be able to add a new record and "save and close" whereby I will trigger the append query to add the new record only.
Thanks for taking this challenge.
Sample Data is that the hours table has two records of data for each column where the Hours IDs are 43, and 8. the other data doesn't matter so I won't bore anyone with all the column data. RE-running the append query would previously add two more records with the same data and IDs 43, and 8. With the new solution below I now get no records added if the records being inserted already exist in the invoice line items table.

OK I did solve that now by inserting the following after the AND"
("ID"<>(SELECT [tblInvoiceLineItems].[HoursID] FROM [tblInvoiceLineItems])));

I didn't realize I needed a second SELECT statement to compare the Hours IDs with the Hours ID value in the target table. It works fine for this table and query but not for my other one which is similar, but I guess I am missing the forest for the trees here. If anyone wants to take a stab at it maybe you can spot my mistake.

This one has the following table:
[Project Expenses].Employee, [Project Expenses].[Expense Date], [Project Expenses].[Expense Code], [Project Expenses].Amount, [Project Expenses].Amount,  ID

SQL:
INSERT INTO tblInvoiceLineItems ( ProjectID, ProjectName, Investigator, ExpenseDate, ExpenseCode, ExpenseAmount, TotalCharges, ExpensesID )
SELECT Projects.ID, Projects.[Project Name], [Project Expenses].Employee, [Project Expenses].[Expense Date], [Project Expenses].[Expense Code], [Project Expenses].Amount, [Project Expenses].Amount, [Project Expenses].ID
FROM Projects LEFT JOIN [Project Expenses] ON Projects.ID = [Project Expenses].Project
GROUP BY Projects.ID, Projects.[Project Name], [Project Expenses].Employee, [Project Expenses].[Expense Date], [Project Expenses].[Expense Code], [Project Expenses].Amount, [Project Expenses].ID
HAVING (((Projects.ID)=[enter id]) AND ([Project Expenses].[ID]<>(SELECT [tblInvoiceLineItems].[ExpensesID] FROM [tblInvoiceLineItems])));

So I did a similar SELECT statement to compare the Expense IDs getting inserted with the Expense IDs already inserted into the same Invoice items table. However when I re-run the append query I get a message "at most one record will be added", but then none are added. There are two records with with the IDs of 2 and 16 for this part of the invoice.

Possibly my entire approach is inefficient to combine records from the two tables into an invoice line item table from which I can display the line items and the total for the invoice/report. Even if someone has a better idea, I find it valuable to learn this append technique should I ever need it as the only or best solution.
Thanks to all who contribute.

Comment: Pretty impossible to diagnose without seeing:  1) Sample Data, 2) Current Results, 3) Desired Results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick glance Im guessing that [Project Hours].ID should only ever go into the tblInvoiceLineItems  table once??

How about changing it to

```
INSERT INTO tblInvoiceLineItems (
ProjectID
,ProjectName
,Investigator
,DateWorked
,BillableHours
,Charge
,TotalCharges
,WorkCode
,[WorkCodeText]
,HoursID
)
SELECT DISTINCT [Project Hours].Project
,[Project Hours].ProjectName
,[Project Hours].Investigator
,[Project Hours].[Date Worked]
,[Project Hours].[Billable Hours]
,tblWorkCodes.Charge
,[Project Hours] ! [Billable Hours] * [tblWorkCodes] ! [Charge] AS [Total Service Charges]
,[Project Hours].[Work Code]
,tblWorkCodes.WorkCode
,[Project Hours].ID
FROM tblWorkCodes
INNER JOIN [Project Hours] ON tblWorkCodes.WorkCodeID = [Project Hours].[Work Code]
WHERE [Project Hours].ID NOT IN (SELECT HoursID FROM tblInvoiceLineItems  where hoursID is not null) AND (
    (([Project Hours].Project) = [Enter ID])
    AND (
        ([Project Hours].ID) IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT [Project Hours].ID
            FROM [Project Hours]
            )
        )
    );
```

I added the hoursid is not null to the not in as not in does some "interesting" things if there is a null value in there at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using the NOT NULL, I will try to fit it into the solution I created above which reads after the WHERE:
((([Project Hours].Project)=[Enter ID]) AND ("ID"<>(SELECT [tblInvoiceLineItems].[HoursID] FROM [tblInvoiceLineItems])));

does NOT IN equate to <> and should I use that instead?

Comment: Thanks again Andrew! I removed my solution and tested yours and it worked fine, and I think your solution is better so I am using it instead. I also adapted it to work for the Project Expenses table insert as well like this:
WHERE [Project Expenses].ID NOT IN (SELECT ExpensesID FROM tblInvoiceLineItems  where ExpensesID is not null) 
AND ( ( [Project Expenses].Project) = [Enter ID]  );

I hope I can help someone else the way you just helped me. I certainly appreciate it and I do answer whatever questions I can. , about whatever topics I am able.